Advanced Wallet Integrations
I’m building a React application that connects to Solana wallets using the Wallet Adapter library. The goal is to display an admin panel in the frontend only for users whose wallet addresses are whitelisted. The verification happens through a Node.js backend, which checks the wallet address against a list of admin addresses stored in MongoDB.
Once the backend verifies that the wallet is whitelisted, the user must sign a transaction to confirm ownership, after which the admin panel becomes visible.
I've been trying hard to implement this, but still no result. Does anyone here know how to get this done?
I am using:
Backend (Node.js + Express.js)
•   Runtime: Node.js
•   For running server-side JavaScript.
•   Framework: Express.js
•   A web application framework for building RESTful APIs.
•   Database: MongoDB

Frontend (React.js)
•   Framework: React.js
•   A JavaScript library for building user interfaces.
•   Wallet Integration:
•   Solana Wallet Adapter (@solana/wallet-adapter-react, @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui):

Thanks!
